# NumPy script to convert BGR to HSL and back

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, image

This is a NumPy script that converts BGR arrays to HSL arrays and back, without using OpenCV. Input and output values are arrays of 3 dimensions with values ranging from 0 to 1, the shape of the arrays are `(height, width, 3)` and the data type is `float`.

I will use it in my GUI program, to implement non-separable blend modes, I have implemented 24 separable blend modes, I posted them on [GitHub](https://github.com/Estrangeling/Eleyi/blob/main/blending_modes.py), I implemented them because I haven't found them in `cv2`. I implemented them according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes), [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1), [this](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html), and [PhotoshopMathFP.glsl](https://gist.github.com/damienmortini/1dbfc4fb420420acf70d) .

I didn't use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL)` because all my image operations are in `float` domain.

I implemented all the code entirely by myself, without outside help, I haven't used a single if statement in actual computation, except for one that checks whether further operations are needed, everything is done using boolean masks, and I made the code as efficient as I can make it. I ported the code from PhotoshopMathFP.glsl to NumPy, that is all.

---

### ***Code***

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Tuple


def BGR_to_HSL_saturation_1(
    hsl: np.ndarray,
    mina: np.ndarray,
    maxa: np.ndarray,
    delta: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    quotient = np.ones(shape=hsl.shape[:2], dtype=float)
    safe = (mina != 0) | (maxa != 0)
    quotient[safe] = delta[safe] / (mina[safe] + maxa[safe])
    return np.clip(quotient, 0, 1)


def BGR_to_HSL_saturation_2(
    hsl: np.ndarray,
    mina: np.ndarray,
    maxa: np.ndarray,
    delta: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    quotient = np.ones(shape=hsl.shape[:2], dtype=float)
    safe = mina + maxa < 2
    quotient[safe] = delta[safe] / (2 - mina[safe] - maxa[safe])
    return np.clip(quotient, 0, 1)


def BGR_to_HSL_helper_1(
    hsl: np.ndarray,
    mina: np.ndarray,
    maxa: np.ndarray,
    delta: np.ndarray,
    mask: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    more = ~(less := hsl[..., 2] < 0.5) & mask
    less &= mask
    hsl[..., 1][less] = BGR_to_HSL_saturation_1(hsl, mina, maxa, delta)[less]
    hsl[..., 1][more] = BGR_to_HSL_saturation_2(hsl, mina, maxa, delta)[more]
    return hsl


def BGR_to_HSL_delta(
    delta: np.ndarray, hsl: np.ndarray, img: np.ndarray, maxa: np.ndarray
) -> np.ndarray:
    ndelta = np.ones_like(hsl)
    safe = delta != 0
    delta = delta[safe, np.newaxis]
    ndelta[safe] = ((maxa[safe, np.newaxis] - img[safe]) / 6 + delta / 2) / delta
    return ndelta


def BGR_to_HSL_helper_2(
    hsl: np.ndarray,
    img: np.ndarray,
    maxa: np.ndarray,
    delta: np.ndarray,
    mask: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    delta = BGR_to_HSL_delta(delta, hsl, img, maxa)
    maxi = img == maxa[..., np.newaxis]
    for index, offset, color_a, color_b in (
        (0, 2 / 3, 1, 2),
        (1, 1 / 3, 2, 0),
        (2, 0, 0, 1),
    ):
        maski = maxi[..., index] & mask
        hsl[..., 0][maski] = (offset + delta[..., color_a] - delta[..., color_b])[maski]

    hsl[..., 0] %= 1
    return hsl


def BGR_to_HSL(img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    delta = (maxa := img.max(axis=-1)) - (mina := img.min(axis=-1))
    hsl = np.zeros_like(img)
    hsl[..., 2] = (maxa + mina) / 2
    mask = delta != 0.0
    if mask.any():
        hsl = BGR_to_HSL_helper_1(hsl, mina, maxa, delta, mask)
        hsl = BGR_to_HSL_helper_2(hsl, img, maxa, delta, mask)
    return hsl


def Hue_to_color(f1: np.ndarray, f2: np.ndarray, hue: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    hue %= 1
    color = np.zeros_like(hue)
    gmask = mask = hue < 2 / 3
    color[mask] = (f1 + (delta := f2 - f1) * (2 / 3 - hue) * 6)[mask]
    gmask |= (mask := hue < 0.5)
    color[mask] = f2[mask]
    gmask |= (mask := hue < 1 / 6)
    color[mask] = (f1 + delta * 6 * hue)[mask]
    mask = ~gmask
    color[mask] = f1[mask]
    return color


def HSL_to_BGR_helper(hsl: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray]:
    bgr = np.zeros_like(hsl)
    empty = (y := hsl[..., 1]) == 0
    bgr[empty] = np.dstack([z := hsl[..., 2]] * 3)[empty]
    f2 = np.zeros_like(y)
    mask = (less := z < 0.5) & (full := ~empty)
    f2[mask] = (z * (1 + y))[mask]
    mask = ~less & full
    f2[mask] = (y + z - y * z)[mask]
    f1 = 2 * z - f2
    return bgr, f1, f2, full


def HSL_to_BGR(hsl: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    bgr, f1, f2, full = HSL_to_BGR_helper(hsl)
    bgr[..., 0][full] = Hue_to_color(f1, f2, (x := hsl[..., 0]) - 1 / 3)[full]
    bgr[..., 1][full] = Hue_to_color(f1, f2, x)[full]
    bgr[..., 2][full] = Hue_to_color(f1, f2, x + 1 / 3)[full]
    return bgr


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cv2

    shape = (36, 64, 3)
    zeros = np.zeros(shape)
    assert np.array_equal(BGR_to_HSL(zeros), zeros)
    assert np.array_equal(HSL_to_BGR(zeros), zeros)
    ones = np.ones(shape)
    assert np.array_equal(HSL_to_BGR(BGR_to_HSL(ones)), ones)
    for _ in range(256):
        bools = np.random.choice((0.0, 1.0), size=shape)
        assert np.isclose(HSL_to_BGR(BGR_to_HSL(bools)), bools).all()
        grey = np.random.random(size=shape[:2])
        grey = np.dstack([grey] * 3)
        assert np.isclose(HSL_to_BGR(BGR_to_HSL(grey)), grey).all()
        img = np.random.random(size=shape)
        assert np.isclose(HSL_to_BGR(BGR_to_HSL(img)), img).all()
        intimg = (img * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        diff = cv2.absdiff(
            cv2.cvtColor(intimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL),
            (BGR_to_HSL(img) * 255).astype(np.uint8)[..., (0, 2, 1)],
        )
        assert (diff > 16).sum() < 24
        assert not (diff[..., 1:] > 128).any()
```

Because I use `float`s, there is inherent impression, and there is so much conversion going on, the output is different from that obtained from `cv2.cvtColor`, but mostly the difference is small, but `cv2.absdiff` values can be over 250, I think it must be from the hue component but I am not sure.

My code converts from BGR color space to HSL color space, to get the same order as HLS you need to do `hsl[..., (0, 2, 1)]`.

My code works for all inputs, and it is verified to be correct. How can I make it more efficient, and how can I make the output closer to that from `cv2` (that is, when converted like this: `(hsl * 255).astype(np.uint8)[..., (0, 2, 1)]`, the result of `cv2.absdiff` of the converted output and that from `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL)` would be less than the current value)?

---

I just added a new check and I have confirmed that the discrepancy of about 254 for some values is indeed from the hue channel, which is not a big problem, because the hue goes from red to yellow and then green then cyan, blue, magenta and finally back to red, it rotates and will always go back. The value wraps around and so a difference of 254 is just -2, nevertheless it is something to be fixed.

---

### ***Edit***

I just found out there are some huge discrepancies because the input values are invalid, the values inside the result of `np.random.random(size=shape)` would be very likely not be an integer between 0 and 255 when multiplied by 255.

If the values are fractions n / 255 where n is an integer between 0 and 255, my code gives the correct output, I tested with this:

```py
byte = range(256)
colors = np.array(np.meshgrid(byte, byte, byte), dtype=np.uint8).T.reshape(-1, 3)
img = colors.reshape((4096, 4096, 3))
assert not (
    cv2.absdiff(
        cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL),
        (BGR_to_HSL(img / 255) * 255).astype(np.uint8)[..., (0, 2, 1)],
    )
    > 1
).any()
```

I have converted all 16777216 colors and the absolute difference is never greater than 1.

So there wasn't actually a problem.

Comment: Have you run the code through Mypy? I don’t think all your type annotations are correct…

Comment: _without using OpenCV_ - then why do you `import cv2`?

Comment: That hasn't been made obvious, since you're running your verification routine in global code with no named function or comments. Anyway, I'll address this in a review.

Comment: For function `BGR_to_HSL_saturation_1`, why does it accept `hsl`? I'd expect that it accepts something called like `bgr`, and returns HSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the code easy to read; there are no legibility issues (within the context that you need to understand Numpy).

It's a good idea that you're doing division safety checks, but you should simplify them. For instance, this:

```py
    safe = (mina != 0) | (maxa != 0)
    quotient[safe] = delta[safe] / (mina[safe] + maxa[safe])
```

should really just be

```py
denominator = mina + maxa
safe = denominator != 0
quotient[safe] = delta[safe] / denominator[safe]
```

This also better handles the case where `mina` and `maxa` are safe individually but their sum is not.

There are many argument names that appear to be errors. For any `BGR_to_HSL` function, I would expect an argument name of `bgr` and not `hsl`.

Where possible, convert module calls to instance calls, e.g. `np.clip(quotient)` becomes `quotient.clip()`.

From this expression:

```
((maxa[safe, np.newaxis] - img[safe]) / 6 + delta / 2) / delta
```

You can divide out `delta` from the last term and just `+ 0.5`.

`%= 1` is fine, but you might see a performance difference if you switch to a non-division method such as subtracting the result of `np.fix()`.

Your functions could use `"""` docstrings.

Everything under your `__main__` guard is *still in the global scope*. Put it in a function.

`np.isclose().all()` is just `np.allclose()`.

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point arithmetic is very slow and since you're doing a lot of it, it plays a major part in slowing things down. Since you're dealing with colours, you can replace floats with ints in the range from 0 to 255.

---

The code has a lot of readability issues.

Variable names are very hard to discern for people not familiar with the subject. This applies to almost every name here really.

You're trading readability off for efficiency, so to keep the code readable you need to add comments explaining what is going on. This is the case for all low-level programming and for bitwise operations in particular.

There are a lot of magic numbers (e.g. 1/3, 1/6, 24), they can be given meaningful names.

```
hsl: np.ndarray,
img: np.ndarray,
maxa: np.ndarray,
delta: np.ndarray,
mask: np.ndarray,
```

I see almost no point in specifying that those names refer to NumPy ndarrays if you're not telling us what types can actually go into these arrays (but a trailing comma is always appreciated).

Comment: “Floating-point arithmetic is very slow” This is simply not true in my experience. “Since you're dealing with colours, you can replace floats with ints in the range from 0 to 255.” This is also not true. Converting RGB to HLS (or any other color space really) and then back using integers will result in different colors because if rounding errors, which can be quite extreme in some cases involving angles. It depends on what you do with colors if an 8-bit integer is enough or not. And often it is so much more convenient working in floating-point, where you don’t have to worry about overflow.

Comment: Re. numpy types, it's true that not describing what types go in the arrays is a problem, but it's false that you're better off not writing the typehint at all. To improve this, one solution is https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html